# Should I consider building a mining rig with PoS being so close?

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake

I am just curious if in your opinion it is worth building a small rig.

Probably looking at 2 or 3 Radeon 7950s or R7 370's and going from there, I am  a little worried about the proof of stake changeover. It might be my understanding of the concept but am I right in thinking my rig will be obsolete (for mining ethereum) when this change happens?

Cheers.

Comment: Tbh, I don't think PoS is _so close_.

Comment: Obviously, PoS is not the problem today and even if we wouldn't have other problems I also don't think that PoS is so close...

Comment: There's a little too much speculation here that I think this should be closed as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

Serious Cloud mining companies like Genesis and Hashflare for example, I think they know the switch to PoS but they are still selling 1 year contracts. That's why i want to try anyway to build my rig (not very expensive, 1000€). That's my opinion :)

Edit: Just read they will switch your eth contract to x11 contract... So i don't know. i hope in new coins to mine.

Comment: FYI.. well, I want to share that wwww.genesis-mining.com does not have more contract with Ethereum, until now Date(08.31.16).